# ios Swift Handling completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
let url = NSURL(string:String(format:"%@", strURL as String))
imgPhoto.load(url!, placeholder: GRAPHICS.MS_PLACEHOLDER(), completionHandler: nil)
```

I am trying to download image from URL. It is working fine. But after downloading the image I have to handle `completionHandler`. How do I do this?

Comment: You just need to pass the `closure` in the `completionHendler` parameter instead of nil.

Comment: please give an example

Comment: Can you give me the name of library that you are using for downloading image?

Comment: Is this load method created by you?

Comment: i did not create that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how your code should look like

```
let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
    println(self)
}

let url = NSURL(string: "http://placehold.it/350x150")

self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage:yourplaceholder, completed: block)
```

What you need to pass is `SDWebImageCompletionBlock`

Comment: i want to have both placeholder image and completion handler

Answer (score 0):

use  pod 'Kingfisher' in Podfile 
import Kingfisher  in your view controller.

make a IBoutlet of imageview.

let url = "imageurl"

in viewdidload

ImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(url)!)!, placeholderImage: "your place holder image")